# reordering includes causes runtime error

Tags: c++, linux, dll, include

One of my script file(.scnp)included the following headers as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kel.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "sigtypes.h"

#include "ScriptInterface.h"
#include "../saf/SAF_Scripts.h"
```

This type of header files include gives an error in GDB saying

> "symbol lookup error: /xxx/xxxx.so: undefined symbol:
>   _Z16KEL_MEM_AllocateP19KEL_MEM_tPoolHandlej.

Included file after

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ScriptInterface.h"
#include "kel.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "sigtypes.h"

#include "../saf/SAF_Scripts.h"
```

ScriptInterface.h

```
extern "C"
```

{

```
#include "kel.h"

#include "process.h"

#if defined()

#include "sigtypes.h"

#endif

}
```

The scripts run successfully. What could be the problem? I have found the responsible method for this problem by using "c++filt" but don't know how to proceed further. Please help

Comment: Do you use include-guard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)?

Comment: Even if i remove
#include "kel.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "sigtypes.h"
these header files also script is running successfully

Comment: Why not? Just do it, the problem will be solved by it self :)

Comment: Still the same error!!! :(

Comment: Any other ways to solve this? What exactly is the problem?